# private memory of an empty python process forked by Python multiprocessing

Tags: python, memory, multiprocessing, copy-on-write, huge-pages

I'm creating several child processes via Python multiprocessing, but these child processes use a lot heap private memory even when they're empty processes. This situation is getting worse when running on RHEL with THP(Transparent Hugepage) enabled.

- what's in an empty child process's heap private memory?
- Under linux COW (copy-on-write), shouldn't child process shares all memory as it doesn't created/modify any mem pages? or the child process is
  trying to modify/write mem pages, then what kind of data it's trying
  to modify/write?
- or it's due to like python object reference count or something?

**Here is a simple example to demo this:**

```
import os
import multiprocessing

print parent process's heap memory in /proc/<pid>/smaps

def emptyProcess():
    print child process's heap memory in /proc/<pid>/smaps
    return

multiprocessing.Process(name='p1', target=emptyProcess).start()
```

**Output:**

```
parent:  pid: 20920:   rss:8228864, shr:2781184, priv:5447680, swap:0, pss:6154240

child: pid: 20921:   rss:6397952, shr:5472256, priv:925696, swap:0, pss:3381248
```

what's in child process's priv memory (925696B, or 664KB in heap)?

***Parent process heap memory:***

> 006cc000-00be4000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                                  [heap]
>
> Size:               5216 kB
>
> Rss:                4120 kB
>
> Pss:                4120 kB
>
> Shared_Dirty:          0 kB
>
> Private_Dirty:      4120 kB
>
> Referenced:         4120 kB
>
> Anonymous:          4120 kB
>
> AnonHugePages:         0 kB
>
> KernelPageSize:        4 kB

***Child process heap memory:***

> 006cc000-00be4000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                                  [heap]
>
> Size:               5216 kB
>
> Rss:                4396 kB
>
> Pss:                2530 kB
>
> Shared_Dirty:       3732 kB
>
> Private_Dirty:       664 kB
>
> Referenced:          676 kB
>
> Anonymous:          4396 kB
>
> AnonHugePages:         0 kB
>
> KernelPageSize:        4 kB

Answer (score 1):

One of the primary things in each process is the Python interpreter / VM. If this were a C program, you'd see a much different picture, but even with an "empty" Python process, you still incur the overhead of an interpreter unless you use threading. Each Python interpreter has a chunk of heap, stack and code, and Python's multiprocessing is a wrapper (as far as I know) around Linux processes; so basically you are dealing with `fork()`. Forking a new process means you get a new Python interpreter. Even though the OS is pretty smart about Copy On Write, the overhead of the Python interpreters add up.

My recommendation would be to try Python threads, or switch this to a non-interpreted language to reduce the process overhead.

Comment: Thanks Melvin, but if I allocate a big memory (~2GB, complex python objects) in parent process before forking the new child process, the private memory of the new forked child process will increase to like 100MB, any idea to explain this?

Comment: Private memory increases to 100MB? I'm not sure I follow, if it is 2GB before the fork, what does it increase to after?